# How to forward a domain on IIS on windows 7

Tags: iis7, domain-forwarding, localhost, windows-7

Briefly my question is about combining my registered domain with the websites listening on port 80/8080 on my server.

I have a web server IIS on windows 7 and two web sites listening on port 80 and 8080.
I have successfully forwarded any incoming request to port 80 and 8080 to my web server.
So everything works like a charm when I try to access these websites entering `http://myglobalip:80/Index.aspx` or `http://myglobalip:8080/Index.aspx` from a computer outside of the local network.

So I have a domain registered, lets say `www.mydomain.com`. What steps should I follow in which sequence? What should I consider to do? I need a step by step guide to follow.

I have registered my domain on Godaddy's website and only configured forwarding so the domain forward to my webserver but when I attempt to access the web page, It always try and try until It times out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is add an A Record through the Go Daddy interface:

http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#arecs

Once you have the A record you can bind it in IIS (Right click the website, edit bindings)

and then hopefully it should work!